# GridView button with condition

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, sqldatareader

I have a gridview with 3 columns Name,Surname,Change(ButtonField column) which is populated from an SqlDataReader with the following code

```
               SqlCommand sqlCommand = new SqlCommand("select * from Empl where userId ='" + userid + "'", sqlConnection);
            sqlConnection.Open();

            SqlDataReader reader = sqlCommand.ExecuteReader();

            GridView1.DataSource = reader;
            GridView1.DataBind();
```

In my database there are 4 columns UserId,Name,Surname,Change(bit). How can i show the button change only when Change(bit) column is true inside the database?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do like..

```
<asp:TemplateField>
      <ItemTemplate>
         <asp:Button ID="btnChange" runat="server" Text="Change" 
              Visible='<%# (Boolean) Eval("Change") %>' />
      </ItemTemplate>
 </asp:TemplateField>
```

As you mentioned in the comment you are getting error on the above code, you try like...

```
Visible='<%# Convert.ToBoolean(Eval("Change")) == true ? true : false %>'
```

Comment: hm i tried this but i got an error `code`         <Columns>
            <asp:ButtonField ButtonType="Button" CommandName="Select" HeaderText="Approve" 
                ShowHeader="True" Text="Approve" Visible='<%# (Boolean) Eval("changed") %>'  />
        </Columns>

Comment: This will not work for ButtonField, you have to make it Template Field.

Comment: you mean like this? `code` <Columns>
            <asp:TemplateField>
      <ItemTemplate>
         <asp:Button ID="btnChange" runat="server" Text="Change" 
              Visible='<%# (Boolean) Eval("Changed") %>' />
      </ItemTemplate>
 </asp:TemplateField>
        </Columns> `code` I get an error again.

Comment: Exception Details: System.InvalidCastException: Specified cast is not valid.

Comment: you can change this Visible='<%# (Boolean) Eval("Change") %>' with Visible='<%# Convert.ToBoolean(Eval("Change")) == true ? true : false %>'

Comment: @pikk let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/2630/discussion-between-muhammad-akhtar-and-pikk)